# Calculating a Hausdorff Dimension from Formula

Tags: logarithms, limsup-and-liminf, dimension-theory-analysis

I am having difficulty computing the following formula for the Hausdorff Dimension for a type of Moran set called a *[partial homogenous Cantor set](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~djfeng/fengpapers/old-papers/FWW_SC.pdf)*.

$\displaystyle\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\log n_1...n_k}{-\log c_1...c_kc_{k+1}n_{k+1}}$

Where $n_1=2, n_{k+1}=[((n_1...n_k)^{\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{s}})^\frac{s}{1-s})]; c_k=n_k^{-\frac{1}{s}}$. Note that $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $c_k\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

My purpose of performing this calculation is to check that the above formula is $<s$ for $r,s\in(0,1)$ as is claimed in this [paper](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~djfeng/fengpapers/old-papers/FWW_SC.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Write $n_1\cdots n_k=m_k$. Then your $\liminf$ is
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log m_k}{-\log(m_k^{-1/s}n_{k+1}^{1-1/s})}=
\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log m_k}{-\log(m_k^{-1/s}[m_k^{(1/r-1/s)s/(1-s)}]^{(s-1)/s})}.
$$
The integer part is at least $m_k^{1/r-1/s}$ and less than $(2m_k^{(1/r-1/s)s/(1-s)})^{(s-1)/s})=2^{(s-1)/s}m_k^{1/r-1/s}$. Therefore, your $\liminf$ is
$$
\frac{\log m_k}{-\log(m_k^{-1/s}m_k^{1/r-1/s})}=\frac{1}{-1/r+2/s}
$$
(since $m_k$ is at least $2$, which ensures that the extra $2^{(s-1)/s}$ disappears).

I must say that I find curious that you mention nothing about the choice of $r$ and $s$ (which is not discussed in the paper that you mention). Of course, it would be nice that $s<2r$ but this probably depends on your specific construction.

Comment: Yep.  That is what I am getting. I am afraid the result just does not make sense (to me) in the context of the paper.  Namely, the result needs to be less than s for 0<r<s<1 which it is clearly not.

Comment: So then perhaps something is wrong with the paper?